Spring Security - Configuration
I'm having a difficult time configuring Spring Security. I'm trying to allow for some routes to be accessible without authentication and secure other routes however .permitAll and .hasRole don't appear to have an impact on my code. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to resolve it? Thank you. Attached is a snippet of my code.
package com.productiv.authentication;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityBasicAuthConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SpringSecurityBasicAuthConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
        authentication.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    /* The below code block allows access to the H2 console */
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().anyRequest();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String methodName = "filterChain";
        logger.info("Executing, " + methodName);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


What's the package of your main/@SpringBootApplication class?

What do you think web.ignoring().anyRequest() does? It basically disables all security as it ignores every request, rendering your furter configuration useless. Your configure method doesn't do anything either

Your security configurations are implemented correctly.
First, remove this (web) -> web.ignoring().anyRequest(). It will ignore all secured paths. Instead you can define which all routes you want to permit like this:
(web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/h2/**, "/api/v1/registration/**")
Your SecurityFilterChain will look like this:
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER")
     // rest of the configuration

Also you need to provide AuthenticationProvider. You current configure method is not doing anything. For example:
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("user"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"))
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}

Read this to understand in details.

Your problem is the H2 database, which requires special treatment to be accessible. Your attempt to solve this problem via web -> web.ignoring().anyRequest() unfortunately disables all security features and no requests at all are being handled by the SecurityFilterChain with the result: welcome everybody, free beer for everyone.
Anyhow, the best way to have an H2 database running for development is to have two SecurityFilterChain in place as follows:
  /* COMMENT OUT your current WebSecurityCustomizer !!! */
// @Bean
// public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
//     return (web) -> web.ignoring().anyRequest();
// }

/**
 * The {@link SecurityFilterChain} for H2 database requests only.
 *
 * <p>Spring MVC requestMatchers() uses by default {@link MvcRequestMatcher}. Since the H2 console
 * is not controlled by Spring MVC, we must force Spring Security 6 to use AntPathRequestMatcher.
 */
@Bean
@Order(10)
// @Profile("development")
public SecurityFilterChain h2FilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
        .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
                /* https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12546#issuecomment-1382891839 */
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2/**")))

        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())

        /* The H2 console runs in a frameset. Thus, we need to set 'X-Frame-Options' from 'deny' to 'sameOrigin'. */
        .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))

        /* Otherwise login into H2 won't work. */
        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .build();
}

@Bean
@Order(20)
public SecurityFilterChain mainFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String methodName = "filterChain";
    logger.info("Executing, " + methodName);

    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
}

Notice the the h2FilterChain which is responsible for the H2 access has a dedicated HttpSecurity#securityMatchers configured, which guards this filter chain and allows only h2 endpoint requests to enter. This way we can configure the requirements for the h2 with this specific filter chain only. All other requests are handled by the mainFilterChain.
